# Transfer data from a mysql database to a sqlite database.(Android-JSON)

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, sqlite, getjson

I am developing an android application that has a sqlite database. I want to transfer data from a mySql database that hosted in a web server to the sqlite database. This data transferring will happen when a user install the application and when there is a change in the mysql database. To achieve this I hoped to uses a JSON web service. I know two ways to achieve this task using a JSON web service.

1. Use separate JSON responses to transfer data from each table of
     mysql database.
2. Use a single JSON responses to transfer data from all the tables of
   mysql database, in once.

My question is: what is the best way to achieve my task when consider the speed and reliability?
(1 or 2)

Comment: do u mean by JSON...?

Comment: @Amritha Sorry for mistake. yes it should be json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this question is primarily opinion based. anyway in my opinion you can create an extra table for recording changes from all the other tables in the database

> > ie. If you have 3 tables like
> >
> > 1.table 1
> >
> > 2.table 2

and

> > table 3

Add another table like `changes_table` or something with fields like `table_name`  and `isChanged` (`boolean`). and listen for the `isChanged` field and sync only that table because it is the best way to ensure data consistency and yields more performance (since transferring the whole database is obviously a heavy and slow process over network).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the database size and your frequency for syncing,

if the database is large in size or will be in future, then the best way to go is fetch data for each table whenever you need it. In case if the data in a single table is too large then you should implement it by paging i.e. pass the parameter in URL for page.

otherwise if the data is not huge then the second way is great that you create a web service that will iterate over all tables and return the JSON for all records.